# Identify the missing number in a set given its superset

Tags: algorithms, bit-manipulation, communication-complexity

Given a set B and B’s superset A, if B is missing 1 number (let’s y) but don’t know which number it is, how to find that number?
That is,

> B’ = B \ {y}, for some unknown element y 
> B = A \ {x}, for some unknown elements x 
> I’d like to know y.

The original context is from [Problem6](https://cs251.stanford.edu/hw/hw2.pdf),

> Miners A and B each have a set of transac- tions in their mempool. Suppose that miner A’s set is a superset of miner B’s. Miner A wants to send to B the transactions that B is missing. The problem is that A does not know which transactions B is missing.
>
> > a. Suppose B is only missing one transaction. Show that A can send a single 32-byte message to B that quickly lets B identify the missing transaction hash. B will send the missing transaction hash to A, and A will send back the transaction data. 
> > Hint: Think of computing the xor of all the transaction hashes in A’s mempool.

So far, my thought is:

> xor all numbers in A = C 
> C xor B = missing number and difference between 2 sets

And I’m stuck at here.

Comment: Is $B'$ a set or an element? Is $A$ a set of numbers? I think you misread the problem statement: Can you [quote it](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)?

Comment: As the question is stated, $A, x$ play no role at all. Something is wrong.

Comment: I’ve quoted the original problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't undestand what is the difficulty you are having.

If $B = A \setminus \{x\}$ for some element $x$, then:
$$
\begin{align*}
\left( \bigoplus_{b \in B} b \right) \oplus \left( \bigoplus_{a \in A} a \right ) &=
\left( \bigoplus_{b \in B} b \right ) \oplus
\left( \bigoplus_{a \in A \setminus {x}} a \right) \oplus x  \\
& = \left( \bigoplus_{b \in B} b \right ) \oplus
\left( \bigoplus_{a \in B} a \right) \oplus x  \\
&= 0 \oplus x = x.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: The x here is the difference of 2 sets, but I’d like to know the missing number in B. If B’ = B \ {y}, and B  = A \ {x}, I’d like to know {y}

Comment: It's difficult to see a solution with two sets $A$&$B$ while convinced there is a more interesting set $B'$.